# iajc fails to weave aspects from a jar but succeedes from class files

Tags: ant, jar, aspectj, compile-time-weaving

So I defined `iajc` task for my project that does intertype declarations just fine, then there is a separate jar task that creates a project.jar.

Then there is `iajc` task for junit test target, this task references the project.jar with the goal of weaving its ITDs into test classes like so:

```
<aspectpath>
<pathelement path="${dist}/project.jar"/>
<fileset dir="${lib.aspect}">
    <include name="**/*.jar" />
    <include name="**/*.zip" />
</fileset>
</aspectpath>
```

That does not work - compiler produces errors like `class "com....Foo" has to implement method doThings() defined in interface Bar`

Then I change the `<aspectpath>` to this:

```
<aspectpath>
<pathelement location="${build.dir}"/>
<fileset dir="${lib.aspect}">
    <include name="**/*.jar" />
    <include name="**/*.zip" />
</fileset>
</aspectpath>
```

which is basically using the intermediate class files generated by the compiler and it works great.

Then I find that if I use the `outjar` option instead of `destdir` in my `iajc` task then that jar can be used in `<aspectpath>`.

So a question and a comment then:

Q. is there some parameter that would make it work with the regular `<jar>` task?

C. the fact that I have to use outjar is not documented at all - the option to output a jar is mentioned but nowhere does it say that that is the only way to produce a jar that will work.