# Ant: Weave aspects both from library and user aspects

Tags: java, ant, compilation, aspectj

I have a library created by myself with simple logging annotations and logger aspect.
I have several AspectJ projects where I want to reuse this library compiled into the jar.
Library is very similar to http://www.jcabi.com/ library with it's @Loggable annotation, but has some differences, main difference is that my library aspect tries to retrieve a Username if class of method marked as @Loggable implements HasUser interface (my own interface). Other differences are not so important.

I want an example of Ant script to compile both from library and project aspects.
AspectJ Ant Documentation is too complex for me because I have little experience with Ant.

Partially similar questions are hear:

[aspectj: How to weave aspects from a library into user code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883871/aspectj-how-to-weave-aspects-from-a-library-into-user-code)

[iajc fails to weave aspects from a jar but succeedes from class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035604/iajc-fails-to-weave-aspects-from-a-jar-but-succeedes-from-class-files)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [jcabi-maven-plugin](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-maven-plugin/example-ajc.html), which weaves your `.class` files using AspectJ aspects from your current Maven module (in `src/main/aspect`) and from all its dependencies:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcabi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.19</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>ajc</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```